# 'ED_UNASSIGNED' undeclared during mysql installation from sources

Tags: mysql, linux

I'm getting an error during mysq installation from sources

```
 [  0%] Building C object cmd-line-utils/libedit/CMakeFiles/edit.dir/chared.c.o
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c: In function 'ch_init':
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c:421: error: 'ED_UNASSIGNED' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c:421: error: (Each undeclared identifier is reported only once
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c:421: error: for each function it appears in.)
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c: In function 'ch_reset':
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c:476: error: 'ED_UNASSIGNED' undeclared (first use in this function)
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c: In function 'ch_end':
/root/mysql/mysql-5.5.31/cmd-line-utils/libedit/chared.c:597: error: 'ED_UNASSIGNED' undeclared (first use in this function)
make[2]: *** [cmd-line-utils/libedit/CMakeFiles/edit.dir/chared.c.o] Error 1
make[1]: *** [cmd-line-utils/libedit/CMakeFiles/edit.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
```

How to solve this error?
I checked mysql sources and indeed there is no ED_UNASSIGNED variable.

Answer (score 1):

I had similar error.
I was using different folder for throwing CMAKE build files. From where I used to run "make".

"mysql-5.6.15" source folder
"MySQL Build" folder where I did throw make files and intended to build binaries.

I had a space in that folder name. Removing the space did the trick.
Though I see there is no spaces in your path but still make sure you are using no folder with "space". Having space in build folder also gives errors when your try to build MySQL from source on Windows.